# Install of jspm to ^0.16.34 has no registry property provided

Tags: node.js, jspm

I am fairly new to front end development and am working through  [Brian Noyes Aurelia Fundamentals course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aurelia-fundamentals/table-of-contents)

I have installed the following;

```
node-v4.4.4x64
Git-2.8.2-64
```

Also I ran

```
npm install jspm --save-dev
```

and had this result

[image: error1]

When I ran

```
npm install =g jspm gulp http-server
```

I got messages saying that the following are deprecated.

graceful-fs@3.0.8 and lodash@1.0.2

[image]

then when I ran

```
jsm init
```

I got an error

[image: Install of jspm to ^0.16.34 has no registry property provider]

The package.json file is

```
   {
  "jspm": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.34"
  }
}
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: https://github.com/jspm/jspm-cli/issues/1117

Comment: that was the answer... editing the package.json to include "registry": "npm"  care to write it up as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to user [danzinator](https://github.com/dazinator) on github.

The fix:

Adding in the "registry": "npm" line to Package.json (even though the documentation says by default this registry should be used?)

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "registry": "npm",
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "wwwroot",
      "packages": "jspm_packages"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "babel": "babel-core@^5.8.22",
      "babel-runtime": "^5.8.20",
      "browser-sync": "^2.9.3",
      "core-js": "^1.1.0",
      "gulp": "^3.9.0",
      "gulp-tslint": "^3.2.0",
      "jspm": "^0.16.2"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jspm": "^0.16.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^3.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.9.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Although all I had to do was add the  "registry": "npm" part.  The rest got added when I re-ran jspm init